# Ansi C parameter to the thread function get compiler error

Tags: c, multithreading, parameters

I get error with pararmeter argument of CreateThread function :
error C2440: 'function' : cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(BIGVAR *)' to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE'
For every thread another list of variables for read/write and all other are readable only.
Call thread function directly  thread(bigvar[2]);   works fine.
What I have to do to give every thread a pointer for every variables list ?

```
#define NUM_THREADS 5    
int thread(BIGVAR *bv);    
    
typedef struct typBIGVAR
{
 
 int var1;
 int var2[30];
 
 char var3];
 ...
 // many other variables
 
 }  BIGVAR;
 
 
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

  buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(BIGVAR) * NUM_THREADS);
  Mem = buffer;

  BIGVAR *bigvar[NUM_THREADS]; 
  
  unsigned long ThreadId[NUM_THREADS];
  
  int arrayThread[NUM_THREADS];
  
  
 
  for ( t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++ )
  {
    bigvar[t] = (BIGVAR *) Mem;
    Mem += sizeof(BIGVAR);
  }


  thread( bigvar[2] ); // this works fine 



  for ( t=0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++ )
  {
    

    bv = bigvar[t];
    arrayThread[t] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &thread, bigvar[t], 0, &ThreadId[t]);
    if (arrayThread[t] == NULL)
    {
      printf("Create Thread %d get failed.\n",arrayThread[t]); 
    }
  
  }
 }
```

Comment: Is this for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread function is not of the correct type to pass to `CreateThread`.

The function `thread` is of type `int (*)(BIGVAR *)` but the function pointer type expected by `CreateThread` is `DWORD WINAPI (*)(LPVOID lpParameter)`.  These types are not compatible, and calling a function through an incompatible function pointer type triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change the signature of your function to be:

```
int thread(void *bv);
```

And inside of the function convert the parameter from `void *` to `BIGVAR *`.

Comment: You're right.  I missed the fact that the expected pointer is an __stdcall one.